# in built apps update

Tags: notifications

Every minute my phone seizes and "unfortunately, measure has stopped" pops up. It makes my phone slow. Under application manager in settings, the app is there but I can't update it.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data for that app?

Answer (score 0):

You can only update an application from the Application Manager if the application has an update in the `Google Play Store`. If there is no update, it will not be available in the Application Manager.

Try to delete and reinstall the app. If the issue continues even after that, send a bug report to the app's creator and find an alternative if the issue cannot be resolved by the creator.